# Request to Remove My App from HUAWEI App Gallery

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Request to Remove My App
I followed the instruction to remove the app, but there is no button "Delete App", there is only "Transfer App"

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-delete_app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove application from app gallery please follow below reference link:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-remove_app

More information refer
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-delete_app

Please if your application is under review process, you will be not able to delete the app

If you submitted an application for review and if you want to cancel then you can follow reference link after cancelling  you will be able to delete the application:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-cancel_urge_review